# How I can find a project Django + VueJS Server Side Rendering (use Rest Framework API)?

Tags: django, vue.js

I am finding a project Django + VueJS Server Side Rendering (use Rest Framework API)?
I use Hackernews Demo (VueJS Server Side Rendering Demo Project) and try to make API Rest Framework but I can't.